# Computer Shutting Down at ~50% Battery

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, shutdown

My laptop is unexpectedly turning off when it reaches about around 50% battery, but the actual level can be anywhere between 40% and 60%. It never turns off when plugged in. Whenever it does shut off, I have to plug it in before it turns back on. I thought maybe something was wrong with the way the laptop was reading the battery, so I updated the BIOS. Right after updating, the computer reached 20% without turning off so I thought the problem was fixed. But the next time I used it, it shut down at 40% again.

I know its not a heat issue because it happens whenever the laptop isn't plugged in. I thought maybe my laptop is reading the battery wrong but I don't know how to fix it. I've already completely reinstalled Windows.

Comment: How old is it? Batteries don't last forever.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's less than 1.5 years old.

Comment: Have you calibrated the battery? Most modern laptops have an OEM battery application which includes this in its actions.

Comment: When it shuts down, is the battery hot (if yes then it's discharging too fast)? Have you tried another battery (even a new battery can become defective)?

Comment: Sounds like a bad battery. Unfortunately. It does happen.

Comment: I'm in agreement its a bad battery but if you want to test it further a very easy way is to charge it up to 100% then disconnect from the laptop, wait a day or two put it back in and see if its still within a few percentages of 100%. If it drops down to 90% or so its bad.

Another type of failure causes issues that won't be reflected in this type of test but would lead to more consistent shutdowns. At say exactly 30% each time for example. After which the computer will think from 30% to say 5% within a few minutes (which suggests electrolyte degradation instead of internal resistance.

Comment: Even if its not doing either of those things sometimes batteries can just be flaky (probably due to a manufacturing defect in the grid or anode) and these are hard to deduce except that they show up as performance failure at higher current. So.. a somewhat dangerous test is to try running GPU intensive tasks since they take a lot of current and see if that consistently shuts down the laptop. Its not as sound a test because it might cause file corruption if its writing to disk when shutting down.

Comment: For that last test i mentioned I will usually do controlled load tests with large heatsinked resistors (also soldering irons work great for big batteries XD) but you may not have the means or tools to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking Battery Report,

-> Open cmd in Administrator mode

-> Enter 'powercfg/batteryreport'

-> Go to saved location 'C:\Windows\system32\battery-report.html' & open it.

-> Check Installed Battery 'DESIGN CAPACITY' & 'FULL CHARGE CAPACITY'.

[Installed Battery Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pnnl.png)

It shows the actual Capacity of battery and current charging capacity. If there is big difference than try changing your battery. There might issue of Battery.

Answer (score -2):

Nine battery cells…. in a triangle pile. If some of them were bad or defective, the battery might SHOW full charge, or show even a partial charge, but it won’t be accurate. As soon as you really just drain the good cells, the unit turns off.